# When I try use WebClient's DownloadString I response error (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I try understand how work with api (based on api.vk.com). 
I have created ASP.NET MVC 4 empty project.

It part of Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoginVk()
    {
        vkProvider = new VKProvider();
        vkProvider.Config = new VkAppConfig { AppKey = "5572789", AppSecret = "i2OpN7gj62ddwTqqRJrK" };
        return Redirect(vkProvider.Authorize("http://localhost:56287/User/Access"));

    }

public string Authorize(string redirectTo)
    {
        return string.Format(AuthorizeUri, Config.AppKey, redirectTo);
    }

public ActionResult Access()
    {
        if (Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("code"))
        {
            var code = Request.Params["code"];
            if (ProcessVkCode(code))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }
        }
        return View("Error");
    }

protected bool ProcessVkCode(string code)
    {
        if (vkProvider.GetAccessToken(code))
        {
            var jsonVkAccess = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vkProvider.AccessToken);
            var jObj = vkProvider.GetUserInfo();
            var vkUser = new User
            {
                FirstName = jObj.ToString(),
                LastName = jsonVkAccess.ToString()
            };

            repository.SaveUser(vkUser);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It's part of model VKProvider:

```
public static string AuthorizeUri =
        "http://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&scope=photos,offline,wall,groups&redirect_uri={1}&response_type=code";

public static string GetTokenUri =
        "https://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}";
public bool GetAccessToken(string Code)
    {
        try
        {
            string reqStr = string.Format(GetTokenUri, Config.AppKey, Config.AppSecret, Code);
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            var response = webClient.DownloadString(reqStr);
            AccessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VkAccessToken>(response);
            return true;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Application return error (401) Unauthorized when execute `webClient.DownloadString(reqStr)`. What is wrong?

Comment: This looks like OAuth2? Are you calling the `AuthorizeUrl` to get a valid `Code` for the `GetTokenUri` to use? Your `GetTokenUri` should include `grant_type=authorization_code` if this is a spec compliant (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) implementation.

Comment: What does one of those returned codes look like? Can it be a missing url encoding of it?

Comment: @starlight54, thank you for ur post, I spend half day for solve this problem, but it has not brought results. How I can mark ur post as answer?

Comment: Well I can add an answer, but only if it actually solved the problem! I see now that you are getting the code etc. The fact you're getting a 401 indicates maybe it's just a problem with how you're sending the `client_secret`, you're sure the server wants that parameter in the query string and not as an Auth header?